# HOWTO: Rails show suggestion message if form submitted but value incorrect

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, submit

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br/>
  <span style="color:red;font-weight: normal; font-size:11px; "><%= errors_for(:name, @user) %> </span>
  <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "login", :placeholder => "Your Name" %>      
</div>
```

I have an input like the above and I need the below to happen if the form is submitted but the value entered is wrong (e.g no @ sign in the email or the password does not match the verification) :

[image]

How can I get this small message to appear next to the incorrect field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`client_side_validations` gem](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) for that.